# Getting the maximum number from a continuously updating list

Tags: algorithm, heap

I came across this problem couple of days back in a system design interview. I'm leaving out the extraneous parts to focus on the core section of the problem. It goes something like this.

Let's say we have a set of k,v pairs, the keys being strings, and the values are integers. We can assume there's a fixed set of keys (e.g. k1, k2, ..., kn). There's some agent that pushes these k,v pairs continuously into the system, like a stream. And all we need to do is add the current value to the old value for all the incoming pairs.

Let's take an example. At time `t0`, let's assume we have the following k-v pairs.

```
k1: 100
k3: 200
```

At time `t1`, there are two incoming pairs. `k2: 50`, `k3: 150`. So, at `t1`, the state of the system is:

```
k1: 100
k2: 50
k3: 350
```

The objective is to give out the key which has the max value at a periodic interval. I'm not able to think of any algorithm, which would give better running time than a max-heapify. I thought of building a max heap, and then updating it as each new data comes. For each update, the `heapify()` would take at max `log(n)` time. At each invocation we can then return the root of the heap. But is there any better solution than this one?

Comment: What answer do you want if more than one v is maximal?

Comment: I think in this context, we should return all elements having the max value.

Comment: Seems to me this can be solved in a time linear to the number of changes.

Comment: Are v always non-negative?

Comment: Yes. They are always >= 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep the max value and associated key in memory. Each time you process an incoming key-value pair, compare the new value for the processed key to the max value, and update if you have a new max.

Comment: I'm going through an existential crisis, after seeing your answer :'(. In the actual question, there were many concurrent invocation of this `populateMap()` + `updateMax()` call. But I guess, with proper synchronization it'd work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

It depends (1) whether all of the updates are monotone (2) on your model of computation.

If values only ever increase (monotone updates), then obviously you can just maintain the maximum of all values that have ever existed so far in memory in constant time.

Otherwise, if the values are small integers, then you could use a [Y-fast trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y-fast_trie) to improve the running time to `O(log log M)` where `M` is the maximum value.

If only comparisons are allowed, then `Theta(log n)` is the best you can do, because this structure can be used adaptively to sort, and sorting `n` elements requires `O(n log n)` comparisons. Given an unsorted array, insert each element under a different key. Query the max, set its key to minus infinity (or some value less than the min element), and repeat to read out the elements in descending sorting order.

Comment: Thanks. What could be a reasonable upper limit on these *small* integers?

Comment: @Bitswazsky Theoretically, whatever you want -- that's what the variable `M` is for. Practically, `2^2^x` is a super fast growing function in `x`, so the realities of whatever cache hierarchy you're dealing with matter a lot more than the theoretical running time.

Comment: Why not just keep the max value and associated key in memory, and compare & update it as you process new key-value pairs?

Comment: @Dave What if the present max gets overwritten by a lesser value?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Isn't this just additive? Where does overwriting happen?

Comment: If v can be negative, doesn't that mean that we just have to revert to a previous maximum  k (ie. we only have to check the k that have already been maximum) in the past? I'm envisioning rolling back a stack of maximums of previous periods.

Comment: @jhnc OP states that values are non-negative in the comments. If values could be negative, reverting wouldn't work b/c the prior value may also have been updated (as could all prior values)

Comment: But then won't those values be on the stack?

Comment: @jhnc T0: {a=>10, b=>5}, T1: {a=>-10}. Now we have A=0, b=5, but b was never an additive max

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I discovered that when I implemented the stack in my perl script and saw the output.

Answer (score 0):

Proof of concept Perl implementation. Clearly the debug statements shouldn't count towards time!

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -T

$maxv = undef;
%maxk = ();
%pairs = ();

sub updatekeys {
    my %newpairs = @_;
    warn "updating\n";
    while ( my ($k,$v) = each %newpairs ) {
        warn "testing $k:$v\n";
        my $newmax = $pairs{$k} += $v;
        if ( $newmax == $maxv ) {
            warn "appending $k\n";
            $maxk{$k}++;
        }
        elsif ( $newmax > $maxv ) {
            warn "new max ($newmax); overwriting $k\n";
            $maxv = $newmax;
            %maxk = ( $k=>1 );
        }
    }
    warn sprintf "max=$maxv; k=( %s ); pairs=( %s )\n",
        ( join ',', sort keys %maxk ),
        ( join " ", map {"${_}:$pairs{$_}"} sort keys %pairs );

}

updatekeys ( k1=>100, k2=>200 );
updatekeys ( k2=>50, k3=>150 );
```

If v can be negative, this won't work.